# Gnuplot : Please use between 1 and 7 conversions, of type double (%lf)

Tags: gnuplot

Hi I'm new with gnuplot 
I'm trying to display a bar graph like this one:
[image]
to display this data:

```
#Float ADDs Float Muls  Int ADDs        Int MULs
14336       20480       19450           2084
8960        14336       12902           3071
```

using this script that i modified :

```
set boxwidth 0.9 absolute
set style fill   solid 1.00 border lt -1
set key inside right top vertical Right noreverse noenhanced autotitle nobox
set style histogram clustered gap 5 title textcolor lt -1
set datafile missing '-'
set style data histograms
set xtics border in scale 0,0 nomirror rotate by -45
set xtics  norangelimit
set xtics   ()
set title "Number of operation : Radix-2 VS Radix-4" 
set yrange [ 0.00000 : 200000. ] noreverse nowriteback
x = 0.0
i = 22
plot 'dataop.dat' using "Float ADDs":xtic(1) ti col, '%lf,%lf,%lf' u "Float Muls" ti col, '%lf,%lf,%lf' u Int ADDs ti col, '%lf,%lf,%lf' u "Int MULs"  ti col
```

can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of a slightly modified data file and gnuplot script that will give you a plot, although I'm not quite sure if it's exactly what you are looking for.

Datafile:

```
Float_ADDs "Float Muls" IADDs IMULs
14336 20480 19450 2084
8960  14336 12902 3071
```

Changes:

- Do not put a '#' before the header, otherwise gnuplot treats the line as comment and ignores it.
- IF you want to use multi-words column headers you must put them in quotation marks like "Float Muls", alternatively you could use an underscore like Float_ADDs, or just shorten it to one word like IADDs and IMULs

Script:

```
set boxwidth 0.9 absolute
set style fill   solid 1.00 border lt -1
set key inside right top vertical Right noreverse noenhanced autotitle nobox
set style histogram clustered gap 5 title textcolor lt -1
set datafile missing '-'
set style data histograms
set xtics border in scale 0,0 nomirror rotate by -45
set xtics  norangelimit
set xtics
set title "Number of operation : Radix-2 VS Radix-4" 
set yrange [ 0.00000 : 200000. ] noreverse nowriteback
plot 'dataop.dat' using "Float_ADDs":xtic(1) ti col,'' u "Float Muls" ti col, '' u "IADDs" ti col, '' u "IMULs" ti col
```

Changes:

- Mostly modified the plot command
- Use '' to add a dataseries from the same file as specified for the first dataseries.
- Modified the column names to match the datafile, alternatively you could use a column index and hardcode the title.

Comment: i keep getting the foloowing error:

**plot 'dataop.dat' using "Float_ADDs":xtic(1) ti col,'' u "Float_Muls" ti col, '' u "Int_ADDs" ti col, '' u "Int_MULs" ti col
                                    ^
"rad_s1.txt", line 12: Please use between 1 and 7 conversions, of type double (%lf)**

Comment: hmmm, it works for me. I tried with gnuplot 5.0 under Windows and gnuplot 4.6 under Linux and had no problem with it either way. I see you changed the header names slightly. Did you make sure your headers names and the names in the plot command are identical. Also, I used space as separator. If you use tab you could try adding set datafile separator "\t".